Custom factory for Zenject with SubContainer and parameters for Instantiate
I want to implement a custom factory in Unity3D and Zenject.
Context:

There is a Game Object context with PlayerInstaller on PlayerPrefab.
There is Scene context with SceneInstaller.

Goal:

Use the factory to instantiate PlayerPrefab with data like position, rotation, etc. Data could be passed via the Create method(position, rotation) OR be predefined at runtime (parent).
Game Object context returns facade class PlayerFacade to be available in Scene Context via factory, while other objects configured in PlayerInstaller won't be available in SceneContext.

Code that works for me to use sub-container and prefab.
[SerializeField] private PlayerView playerView;

container
  .BindFactory<PlayerEntity, PlayerEntity.Factory>()
  .FromSubContainerResolve()
  .ByNewContextPrefab(enemyPrefab)
  .UnderTransform(worldTransform);

The issue with this code - I can't set position, or rotation upon object creation here.
What I would like to have as behavior is something like this.
[SerializeField] private PlayerView playerView;

container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<PlayerEntity>(playerView)

But instantiation will expect to return PlayerView and not PlayerEntity.

You can probably create your own custom factory class, inject DiContainer into its constructor and handle all the installation yourself in the Create method.

Well, yes, but I can't figure it out. Since If I create custom factory, I still need to bind all dependencies. It's quite messy as a result. And hard to work with.

Yes, a custom factory requires some manual setup. But as it turns out, the implementation of a subcontainer-based factory with parameters is described right in the docs, so that's probably your answer.
